# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 44]

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, prediction

Have a piece of code where i am cleaning the text from the 'Description' column and storing it as "cleaned"

Then I create a ML model using the above as one of my features.

```
X = data[['originalname','cleaned']]
Y = data['Total score']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, 
test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [('vect', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), 
    stop_words="english", sublinear_tf=True)),
    ('chi',  SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')),
    ('clf', LinearSVC(C=1.0, penalty='l1', max_iter=300, dual=False))])
```

> X_train.shape--->(44, 2)
>
> y_train.shape--->(44,)

Trying to train the model gives me the above error

```
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How do I use both 'original description' and 'cleaned' as my feature to predict 'Total score' without the above error ?

Comment: could you show us the full error? Are your features ['originalname','cleaned'] both text strings?

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 44]. The full traceback is too long to paste.
Is there a way i can use both the columns(dtype-object) in my TFID model as independent variables and create a score(target) –